# Combine observables across function call of wrapped "catchError" handler

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm implementing a global error handler for all of my epics, which should handle session errors. My problem is how to combine observables of redux actions in my wrapped "catchError" function.

I would like to keep the behavior of the original catchError operator which  expects an observable as return value.

I already have a solution which expects an array of plain actions. But that's not really what I want.

catchError.ts

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { sessionIsUnauthorizedAction } from '../action/SessionAction';

export default (errorHandler) => catchError(error => {
  return of(
    error.response.status === 401 && sessionIsUnauthorizedAction(),
    errorHandler(error)
  );
})
```

myEpic.ts

```
import catchError from 'my/wrapped/catchError';

export const myEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootAction> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(myAction)),
    switchMap(
      ({ payload: { DTO } }) => {
        return from(backendCall(DTO)).pipe(
          switchMap(
            () => of(
              myActionSucceeded(),
              anotherAction({ id: 'other-payload' })
            )
          )
        );
      }
    ),
    catchError(error => of(
      myActionFailed(),
      anotherAction({ id: 'other-payload' })
    ))
  );
```

When my wrapped catchError operator in the epic gets triggered (by an error) it should not only call sessionIsUnauthorizedAction but also myActionFailed and anotherAction.

Actually only the sessionIsUnauthorizedAction gets called and an error is thrown:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler passed in

```
  catchError(error => of(
      myActionFailed(),
      anotherAction({ id: 'other-payload' })
  ))
```

returns an observable, so you get an observable of an action and other observable

```
export default (errorHandler) => catchError(error => {
  return of(
    error.response.status === 401 && sessionIsUnauthorizedAction(),
    of(myActionFailed(), anotherAction({ id: 'other-payload' }))
  );
})
```

You could concat them

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

export default (errorHandler) => catchError(error => {
  return concat(
    of(error.response.status === 401 && sessionIsUnauthorizedAction()),
    errorHandler(error)
  )
})
```